# How do I add a button beside each node of a TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

How do I add a button beside each node of a TreeView?

Comment: what code do you have so far.. hint you would use the Button btn = new Button() now you have to stub it in your code

Comment: @DJKRAZE: That wouldn't work; he wants it _in_ the treeview.

Comment: This is not possible; you need a third-party TreeView.

Comment: Sorry about that ..I just now realized that... I believe with Telerik controls you should be able to do this I know from experience how powerful they are.. site also lets you demo the product as well

Comment: You are probably getting all these downvotes because people think you are one of those n00bs that show up asking for source code solving their problems. But I do not think you are, so I upvoted.

Comment: This question does not appear to show any research effort.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding a button beside each node of a treeview is difficult. You would have to handle drawing of the treeview yourself, and either draw the buttons yourself and emulate their functionality, or create child button controls and display them in the right places within the tree control and then handle repositioning them when the control scrolls, etc. Either way it is going to be a nightmare.

Luckily, there is an easy way out: you do not have to do any of that complicated stuff, BECAUSE YOU SHOULD NOT DO THEM!

Have you ever seen a tree control with buttons in it? No. Therefore, if your tree control has buttons in it, it will be seen by your end users as bizarre.

What you should do is consider how other applications have solved the problem that you are trying to solve without using tree controls with buttons in them, and do as they do.

Comment: Yeah... But I need one with textboxes... Sucks right? I'm creating a deep copy tools. It needs a checkbox and the ability for the user to rename each node down the tree. :(

Comment: Are you sure you need as many textboxes as there are nodes in the tree? How about just a single textbox, only created when needed, and destroyed as soon as you are done typing in it?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this is to draw tree yourself. Here is a small example (please note that PushButtonState is located inside System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles namespace):

```
public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    private Rectangle buttonRect = new Rectangle(80, 2, 50, 26);
    private StringFormat stringFormat;

    public CustomTreeView()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        ShowLines = false;
        FullRowSelect = true;
        ItemHeight = 30;

        stringFormat = new StringFormat();
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), e.Bounds, stringFormat);
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(e.Node.Bounds.Location + new Size(buttonRect.Location), buttonRect.Size), "btn", this.Font, true, (e.Node.Tag != null) ? (PushButtonState)e.Node.Tag : PushButtonState.Normal);
    }

    protected override void OnNodeMouseClick(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Tag != null && (PushButtonState)e.Node.Tag == PushButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            e.Node.Tag = PushButtonState.Normal;
            MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text + " clicked");
            // force redraw
            e.Node.Text = e.Node.Text;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode tnode = GetNodeAt(e.Location);
        if (tnode == null) return;

        Rectangle btnRectAbsolute = new Rectangle(tnode.Bounds.Location + new Size(buttonRect.Location), buttonRect.Size);
        if (btnRectAbsolute.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            tnode.Tag = PushButtonState.Pressed;
            tnode.Text = tnode.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can achieve this even without creating custom control - just add these event handlers to standard TreeView

Comment: It does add the button. However, the lines are gone. Could we keep the line?